# How to loop through a JSON?

Tags: python, json, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through the json below but i am only getting the 1st item. I understand the specifying the key `[1]` is the reason why. How can I overcome this?

```
for i in testing['Items']:
     MyFunc = testing['Items'][1]['Id']
     Containers = UrlFormater(MyFunc)
```

JSON:

```
{'Items': [{'Id': 'Test1', 'Type': 'Address', 'Text': '', 
'Highlight': '', 'Description': ''}, {'Id': 'Test2', 'Type': 
'Address', 'Text': '', 'Highlight': '', 'Description': ''} 
 }]}
```

Comment: `MyFunc = i['Id']`. That's what the `i` is for in `for i in ...`.

Comment: What's the point of looping if you don't use `i`?

Answer (score 1):

When using a for-loop to iterate through a list you get a variable, which in your example you named `i` which holds the current element of the list. For example if you loop over the list `['Berlin', 'Paris', 'Bern']` `i` is equal to `'Berlin'` in the first pass, in the second pass it's equal to `'Paris'` and in the last pass equal to `'Bern'`. With this knowledge you now can refactor your code to look like this:

```
for i in testing['Items']:
    Containers = UrlFormater(i['Id'])
```